# Should I use polling or sockets in my app/game?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sockets, express

I am building a React browser web-app which communicates with a Node.js server (Express.js) with a REST design, and am deliberating as to which method of data transmission I should implement. My application delivers a game similar to chess. The games are long term, meaning that on average each player makes a move only every several hours.
Each game involves only a small number of players (2-3), although many unrelated games can take place concurrently (thousands).

EDIT: Unlike chess, a user can make multiple consecutive moves while he waits for his opponents. So during the several hour wait for an opponent's move, a user can post 20 or so updates of his own if he so chooses.

Given that I do not need to push a single update to many users, and that I do not need to update when users open/close their game sessions, which method of data retrieval should I use?

- Short Polling?
- Long Polling?
- WebSockets or Sockets.io?
- Server sent events?

All help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I'd probably look into server sent events or a cloud messaging service so the server can push out updates when a user makes a move. No need to keep a connection open for one update every few hours.

Comment: To add on that, polling would only lead to either really delayed updates or unnecessary bandwidth consumption. Sockets on the other hand with less data usage would still need to be kept alive for hours without anything happening.

Comment: @JamesCoyle I have updated my question, apologies. I specify that a single user may make several updates on his own accord while others are inactive, so the server would not in all likelihood be at a complete standstill while players are online.

Comment: Then allow the user to make those moves with standard HTTP requests and then push out a notification to the other user when the turn is over. Every move can be easily handled when it comes in and updates can be pushed out at that point to anyone who needs them. You should also be validating the moves on the server as they come in to ensure no one is cheating.